# How to add a where clause dynamically to query which is generated using nestjs Query Builder?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, query-builder, typeorm

I am working on an API for which the requirement from UI is based on the value of the search field I shall receive the filtered results. There are many search fields on UI.

Example code -

```
  async getRoomsByMember(active: boolean, email: string): Promise<any[]> {
      return await getRepository(Room)
      .createQueryBuilder('room')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('room.member', 'member')
      .where("room.active = :active", {active: active})
      .andWhere("member.email = :email", { email: email })
      .getMany();
  }
```

I shall be able to filter room members dynamically if values entered by a user on filter fields like - member phone number, city, state, country, and zip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there :-)

You can try something like this:

```js
async getRoomsByMember(active: boolean, email: string): Promise<any[]> {
  const query = getRepository(Room)
    .createQueryBuilder('room')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('room.member', 'member')
    .where("room.active = :active", {active: active});
  // Keep adding your other fields like member phone number, city, state, country, and zip, like below
  if(email) {
    query.andWhere("member.email = :email", { email: email })
  }
  return query.getMany();
}
```