# TypeORM queryBuilder chaining

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to implement functionality on TypeORM entities that allows me to do something like the following:

```
@Entity()
class Schedule {
  @Column({ type: 'tstzrange' })
  timeRange!: TimeRange

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  email!: string

  static inRange(range: TimeRange): SelectQueryBuilder<Schedule> {
    return Schedule.createQueryBuilder()
      .andWhere('"time_range" && :range', { range: range.formattedForDb })
  }

  static forUsername(name: string): SelectQueryBuilder<Schedule> {
    return Schedule.createQueryBuilder()
      andWhere('email LIKE :name', { name: name + '%' })
  }
}


// The question: is something like this possible?
const user = Schedule.inRange(range).forUsername(username)
```

Through the documentation that I've seen thus far, existing examples seem to only use at most one `.createQueryBuilder` from where more queries are attached to. The way I'm using above feels like an antipattern to me but I'm not sure what the correct way of handling this kind of functionality would be.

Might there be any way to use TypeORM's QueryBuilder to allow for something like the above? Or what better alternatives are there if I want my application code to be less aware of entity level specifications?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a where clause dynamically to query which is generated using nestjs Query Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980521/how-to-add-a-where-clause-dynamically-to-query-which-is-generated-using-nestjs-q)

Comment: @SohamLawar it unfortunately does not. The above answer is referring to the case where the code is using the same instance of a QueryBuilder. What I'm referring to in my question is whether we can combine different queryBuilder instances into one